# Redirect to different controller on submit button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Here's my problem:

I am having a search form in my partial view which I am using on almost all Views. My search form works fine, when I'm on my search controller. But when I'm let's say on details page and when form is submited it uses my details action, not Search action. So is there a way to redirect to my Search action with search params?

Bellow is my code.

```
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          @Html.DropDownList("Location", new SelectList(ViewBag.list, Model), new { @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Choose Location...", @class = "SlectBox" })
          <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date" placeholder="Choose date...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 40px;">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Regads!

Comment: Specify the action in the form element. But the best way to do this is t generate your html using the HtmlHelper methods - `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", yourControllerName")) {....`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `BeginForm` helper method to construct your `form`. You will then need to specify the `controller` name, `action` method name and any additional `form attributes` that you want to use with your form.

You can try something like this in your view. My `controller` name is Home and my `action` method name is Contact, and I have included `form attributes` `class` and `role` as well:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
}
```

Just insert your `dropdown list`, `textbox` and `submit button`. I hope this helps.